# request.user.first_name does not working in django

Tags: django, authentication

I'm trying to build a authentication based view! My html code is:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <span class="logo">Bookmarks</span>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul class="menu">
            <li {% if section == "dashboard" %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="{% url "dashboard" %}">My dashboard</a></li>
            <li {% if section == "images" %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="#">Images</a></li>
            <li {% if section == "people" %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="#">People</a></li>
        </ul>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="user">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            Hello {{ request.user.first_name }}, <a href="{% url "logout" %}">Logout</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url "login" %}">Log-in</a>
        {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here the line:

```
request.user.first_name
```

supposed to show the logged in username according to Django By Example book.
also when I'm changing the password in firefox it shows this massage:
[image]
But in chrome it works fine in changing password, although the name is not showing in both browser!

My Login page html code is :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>
            Your username and password didn't match.
            Please try again.
        </p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Please, use the following form to log-in:</p>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="login-form">
    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
        <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm stuck really bad :(

Comment: `<span class="user">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            Hello {{ request.user.first_name }}, <a href="{% url "logout" %}">Logout</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url "login" %}">Log-in</a>
        {% endif %}
        </span>`
This is my code that responsible for that, i guess !

Answer (score 1):

This is silly! The problem was I didn't set the user's firstname!
But the second problem is still happening!

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue, but after some research, i found this solution
so try to edit the variable from {{ request.user.first_name }} TO {{ request.user.username}}, so is username not firstname.